# memsql 4.1.7 :KeyError: 'error_platform'

Tags: singlestore

I have been trying to run a single node instance of memsql, however got stuck with it and don't know how to proceed. I did not find much of information on Google.

This is what I did:

1. Downloaded the latest version from http://download.memsql.com/memsql-ops-4.1.7/memsql-ops-4.1.7.tar.gz
2. tar xvf memsql-ops-4.1.7.tar.gz
3. memsql-ops-4.1.7.tar.gz/memsql-ops/memsql-ops start

I got this error in this step:

```
 Exception in thread Thread-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 869, in run
  File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/daemon/manage.py", line 198, in startup_watcher
  File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/network/api_client.py", line 32, in call
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 501, in loads
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
 simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

4. opened this url http://:9000 and this is asking to add the memsql binaries, which I did by the following command `$memsql-ops file-add -t memsql memsqlbin_amd64.tar.gz`

Step 4 remains unsuccessful and I can not add the binaries. I am getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "/memsql_platform/bin/memsql-ops", line 18, in <module>
  File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/cli/client.py", line 197, in parse
  File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/cli/command_file_add.py", line 27, in run
 File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/cli/file_add_mixin.py", line 58, in add_file
 File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/network/api_client.py", line 32, in call
 File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 501, in loads
 File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
 File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Checked the log file and it does not say much about the error.

/memsql-ops report throws this error --> KeyError: 'error_platform'

How to go ahead?

Answer (score 0):

Glad we were able to resolve this on public slack yesterday (http://chat.memsql.com). For anyone else who hits this, you cannot upgrade MemSQL Ops by unpacking the new version and just running it. You need to use the `memsql-ops agent-upgrade` (http://docs.memsql.com/latest/ops/cli/AGENT-UPGRADE/) command to upgrade MemSQL Ops. You can use a downloaded tar.gz via `memsql-ops file-add -t memsql_ops /path/to/tar.gz` and then run `memsql-ops agent-upgrade`.

Comment: Is there a way to clean up the older mem-sql installation completely from the machine?

Comment: This issue is not resolved yet. I installed memsql in a ubuntu 14.04 machine and it worked. However on Redhat enterprise server the errors mentioned above in step 3 and 4 persists.